# How to pass this.props to renderScene in React Native Navigation Experimental?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I wanted to pass component props (`this.props`) to `_renderScene` function.

```js
class HomeContainer extends Component { 

  _renderScene(sceneProps) {
    // <<<<< How do I get Component props(this.props) in here? >>>>
    let route = sceneProps.scene.route;
    if (route.key === 'list') {
      return <Home />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        navigationState={this.props.homeNav}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea I can pass it by `this._renderScene.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor:

```
this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
```

or:

```
<NavigationCardStack
  navigationState={this.props.homeNav}
  renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the props on linking the class to your function to do this you need a 'bind'.

example:

```
this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind (this);
```